# How to group dictionary by dateTime and do a sum on int

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this code :

```
    var tradeReqsBySegment = segGroups.Join(pPeriods, s => s.MarketSegmentId, p => p.EntityId, (s, p) => new
    {
        SegmentCode = s.SegmentCode, // string
        Time = p.StartLocal, // datetime
        TradeRequirement = p.Volume // double
    })
    .GroupBy(s => s.SegmentCode)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(i => i.Time, i=>i.TradeRequirement));
```

I would like the `g.ToDictionary(i => i.Time, i=>i.TradeRequirement))` to be grouped by time, and the `TradeRequirement` to be summed up or averaged. How do I approach this?

Also, is it possible to group the time by month by month basis, like get :

```
Time - TradeReq
01/2013 - 500
02/2013 - 234
...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11574538/298754 for grouping by month.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.GroupBy(gr => new DateTime(gr.Time.Year, gr.Time.Month, 1))
         .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Sum(s => s.TradeRequirement));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get both: `Sum` and `Average` at the same time, using anonymous type:

```
var tradeReqsBySegment = segGroups.Join(pPeriods, s => s.MarketSegmentId, p => p.EntityId, (s, p) => new
{
    SegmentCode = s.SegmentCode, // string
    Time = p.StartLocal, // datetime
    TradeRequirement = p.Volume // double
})
.GroupBy(s => s.SegmentCode)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
              g => g.GroupBy(gr => new DateTime(gr.Time.Year, gr.Time.Month, 1))
                    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key.ToString("MM/yyyy"),
                                  gr => new {
                                      Sum = gr.Sum(s => s.TradeRequirement),
                                      Avg = gr.Average(s => s.TradeRequirement)
                                  }));
```

Comment: Very helpful indeed. :)