# Linq Grouping by Date (month)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sum, linq-group

I would like to know how I could group some data by month and sum a field.
For example I have a list of `MyObjects(DateTimeField, AmountField)`. 
I want to group by `DateTimeField`, but not entire date, just by month, and then sum the `AmountField` for each month.

I don't know why the `objectgrouped` is null?

```
    IEnumerable<MyObject> objectList= GetMyObject();

    var ObjectGrouped = objectList.GroupBy(l => l.ObjectDate.GetValueOrDefault().Month)
                          .Select(lg =>
                                new
                                {
                                    CurrentMonth = lg.Key,
                                    Total = lg.Sum(w => w.ObjectAmount)
                                });

ObjectDate      ObjectAmount

1/1/2013              3.3
3/1/2013              6.9
13/2/2013            5
3/4/2013              3.6
13/4/2013            15.2
```

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574474/linq-get-sum-of-data-group-by-date

Answer (score 6):

<strike>I assume by "month" you mean "month and year":</strike>

To ignore null values:

```
var query = myList.Where(i => i.DateTimeField.HasValue)
                  .GroupBy(i => i.DateTimeField.Value.Month)
                  .Select(g => new {
                            Month=g.Key,
                            Total=g.Sum(i=>i.AmountField) 
                         });
```

to put null values in a separate bucket ("0" month):

```
var query = myList.GroupBy(i => i.DateTimeField.HasValue ? i.DateTimeField.Value.Month : 0)
                  .Select(g => new {
                            Month=g.Key,
                            Total=g.Sum(i=>i.AmountField) 
                         });
```

Comment: No, just the month, because before I get all the data from the current year. But I cant do DateTime.Month, I think is because it is a Nullable<DateTime>, what could I do? Thanks

Comment: How do you want to handle null values?  Do they go in their own bucket or are they ignored?

Comment: It is just a Model and DataBase thing, but it is always not null on the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
var grouppedResult = list.GroupBy(x => x.Month);
```

Comment: I have not a field Month, I just have a field type DateTime, but I only want to group by Month and then sum all the amount of each month.

Comment: class MyModel { public DateTime Time { get; set; } }
List<MyModel > list...
list.GroupBy(x => x.Time.Month);

Comment: I dont know why I cant do that, by the way the DateTime is a Nullable<DateTime>, is because of that?

Comment: @user2112420 did you try `GetValueOrDefault().Month`

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(l => l.DateTimeField.Year * 12 + l.DateTimeField.Month)
                .Select(g => new {
                                Month=g.First().DateTimeField,
                                Sum=g.Select(a=>a.AmountField).Sum() 
                             })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I dont know why I am not getting nothing on the group this is null, and my list has values...