# How can add Query LINQ to get result from table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to display output all month and all price but I want by group month
and sum price each month ex:look how output in photo
[image]

```
[HttpGet("api/recent-reports")]
    public JsonResult GetStatusSummaryRecentReports()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Booking> list = _bookingDataService
                .Query(d => d.BookingDate.Month < (DateTime.Now.Month));

            IEnumerable<int> data_month = list.Select(d => d.BookingDate.Month)
                .Distinct().Take(4);

            StatusSummaryRecentReports obj = new StatusSummaryRecentReports();
            //obj.Total_Order_ByMonth = Total_PriceOreder_Each_Month;
            //obj.Months = Months;

            return Json(obj);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(new { message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is _bookingDataService?

Comment: private IDataService<Booking> _bookingDataService;

Comment: public interface IDataService<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        void Create(T entity);
        T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }

Comment: What if you have same month from different years ?

Comment: same month must same years,

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: each years have month if have more than one month same years i want groupby months . but do not worry about years after get solution i can fexid .my Qs i want Query Linq using lamda expresion to return total price each month

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippets may be helpful:

NOTE: tbl51567840 - it is a table having same data as per your snip

```
                //Solution:1 - step by step
                //Step 1.1 > Create iQueryable view to get desired fields to make it virutal/logical table!
                //It is inline query and it is not executed here until you call ToList at below. So it is just like SQL CTE
                var query1 = (from i in db.tbl51567840
                            select new { Month = i.BookingDate.Value.Month, Price = i.Price.Value });

                //Step 1.2 > Apply conditions and other logic to get desired result
                var result = (from l in query1
                              where l.Month < DateTime.Now.Month
                              group l by l.Month into g
                              select new { Month = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(s => s.Price) }).ToList();


                //Solution:2 Result in one linq query

                var query2 = (from i in db.tbl51567840
                               where i.BookingDate.Value.Month < DateTime.Now.Month
                               group i by i.BookingDate.Value.Month into g
                               select new { Month = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(s => s.Price) }).ToList();
```

Comment: If someone wants to improve answer, please refer this sql file having schema + data from http://txt.do/dzneg

Comment: this soluthion does not help its complex sql i want LINQ new version

Comment: LINQ new version? Which one?

Comment: for ex:List<Student> list = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student{ StudentId=1, Name="Alan", Dob=new DateTime(2000,2,1) },
                new Student{ StudentId=2, Name="Joe",  Dob=new DateTime(1999,2,10) }
            };
//2 - display the oldest student
DateTime min = list.Min(s => s.Dob);
IEnumerable<Student> query2 = list.Where(s => s.Dob == min);
//3 - show students with three letters name only
IEnumerable<Student> query3 = list.Where(s => s.Name.Length == 3);

Comment: IEnumerable<Student> query3 = list.Where(s => s.Name.Length == 3);

Comment: can you explain more about  tbl51567840 ?

Comment: tbl51567840 - it is a sql server database table name having same data as per your snip. In your case, it may be  "Booking".

Comment: but i don't usinf sql server . I used EF work asp.net core 2

Comment: Can you please share your code? and also it seems that your IDataService definition has Query function that needs Boolean expression. So, i am sure that there are ways to extend your template based service class that depends on EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want some piece of advice:

1 - I would suggest taking your Business Logic out of the controller methods. Try to make a new class, in a new folder named SERVICES or BLL and make all the logic from there then calling it within your controller methods.
2- Make the method using the Async Task pattern so you wont see deadlocks in your app until the finished of some task.
3- Use in your controller classes the ActionResult return method instead of JSonResult so you get used with it when you have different returns within your method.

example 2 and 3:

```
[HttpGet("api/recent-reports")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetStatusSummaryRecentReports()
{ 
   // When you call your class that has your Business logic, make it as async task pattern as well, so you will call it using the await keyword such as:
  // MyBusinessLogicClass resultFromBll = new MyBusinessLogicClass();
  // var getResult = await resultFromBll.MethodGroupByMonthAndSum();

   ...your controller code here...
}
```

4- Reference to Newtonsoft.json, look it at NuGet,  would help you a lot with the JSON

Anwsering your question, follow the bellow example from: [Linq get sum of data group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574474/linq-get-sum-of-data-group-by-date)

```
static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<meter_reading>
                   {
                       new meter_reading {Date = new DateTime(2000, 2, 15), T1 = 2, T2 = 3},
                       new meter_reading {Date = new DateTime(2000, 2, 10), T1 = 4, T2 = 5},
                       new meter_reading {Date = new DateTime(2000, 3, 15), T1 = 2, T2 = 3},
                       new meter_reading {Date = new DateTime(2000, 3, 15), T1 = 5, T2 = 4}
                   };
        var sum = list
        .GroupBy(x => GetFirstDayInMonth(x.Date))
        .Select(item => new meter_reading
                            {
                                Date = item.Key,
                                T1 = item.Sum(x => x.T1),
                                T2 = item.Sum(x => x.T2),
                            }).ToList();
}

private static DateTime GetFirstDayInMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Date.Year, dateTime.Date.Month, 1);
}
```